# How to disable scrolling in QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to implement mouse wheel zoom in/out. It works BUT when I zoom in/out, the image is getting smaller AND scrolls up/down at the same time with zoom function. Look like events exist at the same time and work together.

I cannot find how to disable scrolling with mouse wheel. May be there is a way to make possible scrolling only with mouse cursor (by clicking on scrollbar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overriding the main method of mouse wheel but it was causing the effect I wrote above

```
void MainWindow::wheelEvent( QWheelEvent* event )
```

Solved by using event filter. The code below provides zoom in/out with holding ctrl button.

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneWheel)
    {
        ui->GV_image->setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);
        double scaleFactor = 1.15;
        bool ok = QApplication::keyboardModifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier;
        if (ok)
        {
            QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent *scrollevent = static_cast<QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent *>(event);
            if (scrollevent->delta() > 0)
            {
                ui->GV_image->scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
            }
            else
            {
                ui->GV_image->scale(1/scaleFactor, 1/scaleFactor);
            }
        }

        event->accept();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Put this line into your constructor or other your init function

```
    QGraphicsView *GV_image;

...

    ui->GV_image->scene()->installEventFilter(this);
```